# Не работает chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Я пишу простое расширение для браузера хром, в котором мне необходимо обеспечить обмен сообщениями между content-script и .js файлом, вызываемом в popup.html

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <style media="screen">
  body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }
 .main{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
 }
 .turnOn{
  padding: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="message"></div>
 <div class="main"><button class="turnOn"></button></div>

 <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
var button = document.getElementsByClassName('turnOn')[0];
var turnedOn = false;
var messageBox = document.getElementById('message');

messageBox.innerHTML = 'text: ';

button.innerHTML = 'Включить';

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender) {
  console.log(message); // не работает
  var tabID = sender.tab.id;

  messageBox.innerHTML = 'Text: ' + message;

  button.onclick = function(el){
    if (!turnedOn){
      turnedOn = true;
      button.innerHTML = 'Выключить';
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabID,turnedOn)
    } else {
      turnedOn = false;
      button.innerHTML = 'Включить';
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabID,turnedOn)
    }
  }
});
```

delete.js:

```
console.log('at least delete.js has loaded');

chrome.runtime.sendMessage(0, function () {
});

console.log('message sent');
```

delete.js пишет в консоль оба сообщения, тогда как index.js отрабатывает button.innerHTML, но ничего не пишет в консоль, так как, похоже, не приходит сообщение

Answer (score 1):

Уже решил, delete.js отправлял инициализационное сообщение до загрузки index.js